# Spark: How to covert the values of a pairRdd to a Rdd?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pairRdd like this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([{'f':[1,2,3]},{'f':[1,2]}])
pair_rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.keys()).zip(rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x.values()))
reduce_rdd = pair_rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

The output result:

```
[('f', [1, 2, 3, 1, 2])]
```

As the value of `reduce_rdd` maybe very large, so I want to parallelize the value of `reduce_rdd`.

```
reduce_rdd.map(lambda x: sc.parallelize(x[1]))
```

Then something goes wrong.

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Comment: You can't reference spark context in your transformation/action code. Would `reduce_rdd` elements be so large that you want to parallelize them? Are you not able to do those *parallel* transformations before running `reduceByKey` (or maybe use `flatMap` after that)?

Comment: Yes, the value of `reduce_rdd` is a list, so I want to parallelize the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parallelize of `reduce_rdd` by collecting the values.

```
sc.parallelize(reduce_rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x[1]).collect())

#using flatMap transformation
sc.parallelize(reduce_rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x[1]).collect()).collect()
#[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]

#using map
sc.parallelize(reduce_rdd.map(lambda x:x[1]).collect()).collect()
#[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]]

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#if you want to convert rdd to dataframe
spark.createDataFrame(reduce_rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x[1]).collect(),IntegerType()).show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize that I don't need to reduce `pair_rdd`, I just use `pair_rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'f')` to solve my problem.